# Why does `Solve` repeat the same solution twice?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I have the system of matrix equations

```
{s.n == n.s, n.n == 0, s + n == f}
```

where

```
f = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {1,   0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1,   0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1,   0, 0}}
s = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {s31, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, s42, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, s53, 0, 0}}
n = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {n31, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, n42, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, n53, 0, 0}}
```

`Solve` gives

```
{{n31 -> 0, n53 -> 0, s31 -> 1, s42 -> 1 - n42, s53 -> 1}, {n31 -> 0, n53 -> 0, s31 -> 1, s42 -> 1 - n42, s53 -> 1}}
```

i.e. repeats the same solution twice. Why?

Comment: `Solve[{s . n == n . s, n . n == 0, s + n == f}, Reals]`

Comment: @cvgmt Thank you, this works, but it is even more mysterious. The solution is unique anyway, whether over reals or not, right?

Comment: `Reduce` is powerful than `Solve`.   Reduce[{s . n == n . s, n . n == 0, s + n == f}]

Comment: The solution has multiplicity.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Indeed - `Solve[x^2==0]` does the same. Would you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: Or you can add `Method-> Reduce`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiplicity arises from the one equation `n31 n53 == 0`  where Solve regards the two cases separately that only one variable is zero and the other free and yields two solutions (that show the other variable is also zero).

Delete all zeros from equations and reduce it to 5 ones.

```
eqs = {s.n == n.s, n.n == 0, s + n == f};

dc = DeleteCases[eqs /. Equal -> Subtract, 0, {3}] // Flatten

(th = Thread[dc == 0]) // TableForm

Solve[Thread[(dc /. n31 -> 0) == 0]]
(*   {{n53 -> 0, s31 -> 1, n42 -> 1 - s42, s53 -> 1}}   *)

Solve[Thread[(dc /. n53 -> 0) == 0]]
(*   {{n31 -> 0, s31 -> 1, n42 -> 1 - s42, s53 -> 1}}   
*)
```